# In the TypeScript compiler source, is `parsingContext` a blob or an instance of an enum?

Tags: typescript, bitwise-operators

In the TypeScript compiler source, is `parsingContext` meant to be always equal to one of the values in the `ParsingContext` enum? Or is `ParsingContext` a set of flags and `parsingContext` is a blob to be manipulated through bitwise operators?

Support for `parsingContext` being equal to one of the values of the enum (0 -> 22):

- An intended-to-be-exhaustive check for all values of `parsingContext`: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0bb897273fe1e4844f16e341700911e4e730fd82/src/compiler/parser.ts#L1457
- That the type is called "ParsingContext," not "ParsingContextFlags."

Support for `parsingContext` being a blob intended to be manipulated with bitwise operators:

- Reading and Writing through bitwise operators:

  - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0bb897273fe1e4844f16e341700911e4e730fd82/src/compiler/parser.ts#L1680
  - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0bb897273fe1e4844f16e341700911e4e730fd82/src/compiler/parser.ts#L1667

I'm asking here instead of on GitHub because the TypeScript Issues page says to ask questions here instead of on GH and because it's possible I'm just not understanding a common thing people do with bitwise operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the TypeScript compiler source, is parsingContext meant to be
> always equal to one of the values in the ParsingContext enum? Or is
> ParsingContext a set of flags and parsingContext is a blob to be
> manipulated through bitwise operators?

There are different entities called `parsingContext`.

[This one](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0bb897273fe1e4844f16e341700911e4e730fd82/src/compiler/parser.ts#L608)

```
    let parsingContext: ParsingContext;
```

holds arbitrary combination of bit flags (is a 'blob' as you say), is always manipulated via bitwise operators and is never compared directly with values of `ParsingContext` enum, although for some unclear reason it's declared to have `ParsingContext` type.

The other `parsingContext`s are declared as parameters to several functions, and are really meant to be just `ParsingContext` enum values. In fact, values for these `parsingContext`s always come from some function above in the call stack where they are called `kind`, not `parsingContext`. Here is one instance of `kind` in `parseList`  becoming `parseContext` in `parseListElement`:

```
    // Parses a list of elements
    function parseList<T extends Node>(kind: ParsingContext, parseElement: () => T): NodeArray<T> {
        const saveParsingContext = parsingContext;
        parsingContext |= 1 << kind;
        const list = [];
        const listPos = getNodePos();

        while (!isListTerminator(kind)) {
            if (isListElement(kind, /*inErrorRecovery*/ false)) {
                const element = parseListElement(kind, parseElement);
                                                 ^^^^

    function parseListElement<T extends Node>(parsingContext: ParsingContext, parseElement: () => T): T {
        const node = currentNode(parsingContext);
```

All checks for `parsingContext` being equal to some value of `ParsingContext` enum are done in these functions where `parsingContext` does not refer to the `parsingContext` bit flags variable, but is coming as a parameter that was initially named `kind` and was given as a single value of `ParsingContext` enum.

Yes it's confusing, hope that my answer does not add to the confusion :)

Comment: Thank you! I spent 20 minute trying to figure out where `33` came from when there are only twenty-something instances for the enum. Your explanation is very helpful.